# Error while building with Yarn Deployment - Angular Application

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, yarnpkg

While building with Yarn in VSTS I get the error "**could not find a copy of typescript to link in D:\c\2\b\node_modules\rxjs-tslint\node_modules**"

Error: **\hostedtoolcache\windows\yarn\1.12.3\x64\yarn-v1.12.3\bin\yarn.cmd** failed with return code: 1

Looks like dependency issue.

Comment: I was getting this error in Windows, but in Linux distro, even in WSL, it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is defenetly an issue with Yarn with the eslint version.

https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/6285

Had to remove that from --prod version as a work around and have it added to dev only dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what's your dependency structure, but the error actually gives the clue.

Same happened to me just ago - when I upgraded the **`rxjs-tslint`** package from **v0.1.5** to **v0.1.6**, as well as other packages.

Seems like something is wrong with **`rxjs-lint`** **v0.1.6**, better edit your **package.json** to use **v0.1.5** as a *workaround*.

That trick just worked on 3 different projects :)

Comment: Currently I have "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.5" so do you suggest upgrading it to V0.1.6